# webapp project is not created using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I tried to create a webapp project using maven-archetype. The **Java** and **Test** folders are not created automatically. I can see only **resources** and **webapp** folders. Can you please let me know where I am missing?

I followed both the approached, but nothing worked out:
**Approach 1:**
I have installed maven separately and referred to "Maven Installations" in Eclipse using Windows->Preferences->Maven->Installations option.

**Approach 2:**
Installed Maven plugin in eclipse and removed the local points in Windows->Preferences->Maven->Installations option.

I have attached a screen shot of how the created project looks like, where **Java** and **Test** folders are missing

Note: I am not able to attach the image as I dont have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Maven does not create **Java** and **Test** folders if we use the webapp archetype. We have to manually create the **Java** and **Test** folders.